# Windows 8.1 - Command Prompt with encoding error in special chars

Tags: command-line, windows-8.1, character-encoding

I have a fresh install of windows 8.1 and the command prompt is like shown in the image below,that is, special chars with encoding error.
It seems there is not many users with this same problem, since I have found no help out there..

I wonder if there's a way to fix this. I'm using the pt_br version, by the way. And the system is up to date (2014-01-17).

Any help would be nice. Thx.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You're using code page 860.  Switch to code page 850.